# How to return string to original format after modification in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to write a sorting algorithm for sorting filesizes intelligently regardless of the input format. My function is supposed to sort an array of string inputs to give required outputs like so;

```js
input = ["5.1 GB","19934563 B","224 kB","0.55 GB","0.04 kB","0.02 TB","2.4 MB"]
output = ["0.04 kB","224 kB","2.4 MB","19934563 B","0.55 GB","5.1 GB","0.02 TB"]
```

My code changes the input to a specific format so it is easier to work with before sorting the values. It works well for inputs/values with the format of ("filesize whitespace unit"). It currently gives the result

```js
input = ["5.1   GB ","19934563 B"," 224 kB","  0.55 GB ","0.04 kB ","0.02  TB","2.4\tMB",]
output =["0.04 kB ","224 kB","2.4 MB","19934563 B","0.55 GB","5.1 GB","0.02 TB",]
```

**My Question: Is there a way to get back to the original format of the string after sorting or how can I go about getting the required result? that is the filesize string sorted intelligently in the original input format.**

My code is below

```
function sort(fileSizes, descending) {    
    if (!fileSizes.length) return "Enter an List to be Sorted";
    else {
      let validFormat = fileSizes.map((file) => validFile(file));
      if (validFormat.includes(false)) {
        let formarted = fileSizes.map(item => item.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim());
        fileSizes = formarted;
      };
      let sortedFiles = sortSizes(fileSizes);
      if (descending === true ) return sortedFiles;
      if (descending === false) return sortedFiles.reverse();
    }    
  }

//////////////////////////////////////////////
//Helper Functions

//Regular expression for valid input format
function validFile(str) {
  let regEx = /^(-?\d*(\.\d+)?)\s((T|G|M|k)*B)$/;
  let valid = regEx.test(str);
  return valid;
}

 // global comparator array
let sizes = ["B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"];

//Custom Sorter
function sortSizes(arr) {
  // sort by comparator
  arr.sort(function(x, y) {
    var x_res = x.split(" "), y_res = y.split(" ");
    var x_value = x_res[0], x_unit = x_res[1];
    var y_value = y_res[0], y_unit = y_res[1];
    let amount = casting(x_unit, y_unit, x_value);
    if(amount < y_value) {
      return -1;
    } else if(x_value > y_value) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  return arr.reverse();  
}

//Convert file unit for comparison
function casting(unit_from, unit_to, amount) {
  var i = sizes.indexOf(unit_from);
  var j = sizes.indexOf(unit_to);
  var r;
  if(i < j) {
    r = j - i;
  } else {
    r = j - i;
  }
  var i = 0;
  if(r < 0) {
    r *= (-1);
    while(i < r) {
      amount *= 1024;
      i++;
    }
  } else {
    while(i < r) {
      amount /= 1024;
      i++;
    }
  }  
  return amount;
}

console.log(sort(["5.1 GB","19934563 B","224 kB","0.55 GB","0.04 kB","0.02 TB","2.4 MB",], false)); // ["0.04 kB","224 kB","2.4 MB","19934563 B","0.55 GB","5.1 GB","0.02 TB",]
console.log(sort(["5.1 GB","19934563 B","224 kB","0.55 GB","0.04 kB","0.02 TB","2.4 MB",], true)); //["0.02 TB","5.1 GB","0.55 GB","19934563 B","2.4 MB","224 kB","0.04 kB"]
console.log(sort([], true)); //"Enter an List to be Sorted"
console.log(sort(["5.1   GB ","19934563 B"," 224 kB","  0.55 GB ","0.04 kB ","0.02  TB","2.4\tMB",], false));  //["0.04 kB "," 224 kB","2.4\tMB","19934563 B","  0.55 GB ","5.1   GB ","0.02  TB",]
```

Comment: I mean I would just take the approach of `before = []` and `after = []`, before any string modifications. Or simply append while doing the main process, a separate object to reference.

Comment: Convert the values only temporarily in the `.sort()` callback, or use an object (`{ original: ..., modified: ... }`), sort with the `.modified` value and then extract the `.original` values afterwards, or ... -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas My thoughts exactly, nice reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = ["5.1   GB ","19934563 B"," 224 kB","  0.55 GB ","0.04 kB ","0.02  TB","2.4\tMB"]

const multipliers = {
  B: 10 ** 0,
  kB: 10 ** 3,
  MB: 10 ** 6,
  GB: 10 ** 9,
  TB: 10 ** 12,
}

input.sort((a, b) => {
  const regex = /\s+/;
  const [valueA, unitA] = a.trim().split(regex) 
  const [valueB, unitB] = b.trim().split(regex)
  const A = Number(valueA) * multipliers[unitA]
  const B = Number(valueB) * multipliers[unitB]
  return  A - B;
})

console.log(input)
```